# Upgrading to Vapor 4: how to create a model and returning it

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

In my old Vapor 3 code I'm creating models like this:

```
address.create(on: conn).flatMap { savedAddress in
    // do something with saved address
}
```

With the help of the Vapor 4 documentation I'm now passing db to the create function instead of a connection. The issue is, that it seems that flatMap returns Void as I'm getting the following error when I try to access savedAddress: "Value of tuple type 'Void' has no member ...".

How should I rewrite this?

Comment: Hey you could find me in Discord as `iMike#3049` and I'll help you with migration to Vapor 4

Comment: Since Fluent4 returns `Void` on new record creation the workaround is to set id to new record in advance and then retrieve that record from the database by that `id`.

Comment: This sounds like a step backward, that was much easier in v3. Is there really no better solution?

Comment: If you prefer pure SQL then I could suggest Bridges https://github.com/SwifQL/Bridges

Comment: I think I'll wait a couple of days with upgrading the server till there is an official upgrade guide for fluent. If I still have issues, I will take your offer to help me. Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all models in Fluent 4 must be classes, you can rely on reference semantics to do what you want (which is why `create(on:)` returns `EventLoopFuture<Void>`. So in your example, instead of `savedAddress` you can just use `address` as the saved model. When it has been saved, Fluent will set the ID property of your model on the `address` object, which you can then retrieve in your `flatMap` closure with `address.requireID()`